# Retrieving plugin options value saved through setting

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

Looking at this code below it work add options perfectly  and saved them. However I will like to use those data at front page in my plugin short code.

```
class MySettingsPage
{
    /**
     * Holds the values to be used in the fields callbacks
     */
    private $options;

    /**
     * Start up
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        add_action( 'admin_menu', array( $this, 'add_plugin_page' ) );
        add_action( 'admin_init', array( $this, 'page_init' ) );
    }

    /**
     * Add options page
     */
    public function add_plugin_page()
    {
        // This page will be under "Settings"
        add_options_page(
            'Settings Admin', 
            'My Settings', 
            'manage_options', 
            'my-setting-admin', 
            array( $this, 'create_admin_page' )
        );
    }

    /**
     * Options page callback
     */
    public function create_admin_page()
    {
        // Set class property
        $this->options = get_option( 'my_option_name' );
        ?>
        <div class="wrap">
            <h2>My Settings</h2>           
            <form method="post" action="options.php">
            <?php
                // This prints out all hidden setting fields
                settings_fields( 'my_option_group' );   
                do_settings_sections( 'my-setting-admin' );
                submit_button(); 
            ?>
            </form>
        </div>
        <?php
    }

    /**
     * Register and add settings
     */
    public function page_init()
    {        
        register_setting(
            'my_option_group', // Option group
            'my_option_name', // Option name
            array( $this, 'sanitize' ) // Sanitize
        );

        add_settings_section(
            'setting_section_id', // ID
            'My Custom Settings', // Title
            array( $this, 'print_section_info' ), // Callback
            'my-setting-admin' // Page
        );  

        add_settings_field(
            'id_number', // ID
            'ID Number', // Title 
            array( $this, 'id_number_callback' ), // Callback
            'my-setting-admin', // Page
            'setting_section_id' // Section           
        );      

        add_settings_field(
            'title', 
            'Title', 
            array( $this, 'title_callback' ), 
            'my-setting-admin', 
            'setting_section_id'
        );      
    }

    /**
     * Sanitize each setting field as needed
     *
     * @param array $input Contains all settings fields as array keys
     */
    public function sanitize( $input )
    {
        $new_input = array();
        if( isset( $input['id_number'] ) )
            $new_input['id_number'] = absint( $input['id_number'] );

        if( isset( $input['title'] ) )
            $new_input['title'] = sanitize_text_field( $input['title'] );

        return $new_input;
    }

    /** 
     * Print the Section text
     */
    public function print_section_info()
    {
        print 'Enter your settings below:';
    }

    /** 
     * Get the settings option array and print one of its values
     */
    public function id_number_callback()
    {
        printf(
            '<input type="text" id="id_number" name="my_option_name[id_number]" value="%s" />',
            isset( $this->options['id_number'] ) ? esc_attr( $this->options['id_number']) : ''
        );
    }

    /** 
     * Get the settings option array and print one of its values
     */
    public function title_callback()
    {
        printf(
            '<input type="text" id="title" name="my_option_name[title]" value="%s" />',
            isset( $this->options['title'] ) ? esc_attr( $this->options['title']) : ''
        );
    }
```

****I have try something like This below****

```
public function DataToget()
    {   

    $jugHigh=get_option( $this->options['title'] );
    return $jugHigh;
    }

}
```

**I have try to make use of it at front page no luck**

```
if ( !function_exists("getdat") ){ 
function getdat_func() {
$getdatClass = new MySettingsPage();

$output=$getdatClass->DataToget();

$output= apply_filters( 'getdat_func', $output );       
    return $output; 
}
}
add_shortcode( 'getdat', 'getdat_func' );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are saving data to an option named `my_option_name` so your attempt to retrieve data from an option named `$this->options['title']` isn't going to work. You will need something like this:

```
public function DataToget($field = '') {   
  if (empty($field)) return;
  $jugHigh = get_option( 'my_option_name' );
  if (!isset($jugHigh[$field])) return;
  return $jugHigh[$field];
}
```

With a shortcode like:

```
if ( !function_exists("getdat_func") ){ 
  function getdat_func() {
    $getdatClass = new MySettingsPage();
    $output=$getdatClass->DataToget('title');
    $output= apply_filters( 'getdat_func', $output );       
    return $output; 
  }
}
add_shortcode( 'getdat', 'getdat_func' );
```

But really, just roll the shortcode callback into your class:

```
function getdat_func() {
  $output = $this->DataToget('title');
  $output= apply_filters( 'getdat_func', $output );       
  return $output; 
}
```

And add this line to your constructor:

```
add_shortcode( 'getdat', array($this,'getdat_func') );
```

Comment: thank you very much I later got another work around that why I delay in response thank you very much both of your methods worked